# A random variable independent of its order statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, order-statistics

Suppose I have $n$ random variables $X_i \overset{iid}{\sim} f(x_i) $. Is it possible that the $r^{th}$ order statistic $X_{(r)}$ is independent of arbitrary random variable $X_i$?  I really want this to be true, but my gut says no.

Follow-up.  Is is possible to show $X_{(1)}-X_i$ is independent of $X_{(1)} -X_j$ where $i \neq j$.  Now I believe this is true, but again, I am having a hard time being able to show why.

Comment: Do you have a particular distribution in mind?

Comment: What if $F(x)=0 $ for all $x$ less than some number $k$ and then suddenly jumps to $1$? (where $F$ is the cumulative distribution of $X_i$)

Comment: Yes.  Suppose all random variables are 0 with probability 1.